# Parsing ambiguous timestamps

Tags: r, datetime

I have been provided a dataset with an ambiguous date format, e.g:

```
d_raw <- c("1102001 23:00", "1112001 0:00")
```

I would like to try to parse this date into a POSIXlt object in R.  The source of the file assures me that the file is in chronological order, that the date format is month, then day, then year, and that there are no gaps in the time series.

Is there any way to parse this date format, using the ordering to resolve ambiguities?  E.g. the first element above should parse to  `c("2001-01-10 23:00:00", "2001-01-11 00:00:00")` rather than `c("2001-01-10 23:00:00", "2001-11-01 00:00:00")`.

Comment: If they are consecutive in the sense that each day is present, couldn't you just check the range, then create a date sequence over that range, and then add the specific time at each date?

Comment: @beginneR Yes, that's a possibility.  The trick is then correctly parsing the first element of the series, which is a problem I've still yet to solve.

Comment: Can you provide a more representative example? Also, go to your data provider and beat them with a giant zero (make it from cardboard if you don't have one handy).

Comment: @Roland The data provider stubbornly refuses to see the point, which is causing me no end of frustration.  I even sent them the [relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1179) (which I suppose is the digital equivalent of beating them with a giant zero).

Comment: I believe it would be easiest, to (i) create a function that creates this mess from `POSIXlt`, (ii) create all possible datetimes from the first value, (iii) create datetime sequences of the correct length from these starting values, (iv) chose the one which equals the input after the function from (i) is applied.

Comment: @Roland: Itwouldbe more effectivetorandomly removespaces between wordswhenemailing themfromnowon.

Comment: Damn, I've been writing (27/2)-13 this whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pity you for your horrible data vendor, so I decided to try and fix this for you.

```
# make up some horrid data
d_bad <- as.POSIXlt(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by=1))
d_raw <- paste0(d_bad$mon+1, d_bad$mday, d_bad$year+1900)

d_new <- d_raw
# not ambiguous when nchar is 6
d_new <- ifelse(nchar(d_new)==6,
  paste0("0", substr(d_new,1,1), "0", substr(d_new,2,nchar(d_new))), d_new)
# now not ambiguous when nchar is 7 and it doesn't begin with a "1"
d_new <- ifelse(nchar(d_new)==7 & substr(d_new,1,1) != "1",
  paste0("0",d_new), d_new)
# now guess a leading zero and parse
d_new <- ifelse(nchar(d_new)==7, paste0("0",d_new), d_new)
d_try <- as.Date(d_new, "%m%d%Y")

# now only days in October, November, and December might be wrong
bad <- cumsum(c(1L,as.integer(diff(d_try)))-1L) < 0L
# put the leading zero in the day, but remember "bad" rows have an
# extra leading zero, so make sure to skip it
d_try2 <- ifelse(bad,
  paste0(substr(d_new,2,3),"0", substr(d_new,4,nchar(d_new))), d_new)
# convert to Date, POSIXlt, whatever and do a happy dance
d_YAY <- as.Date(d_try2, "%m%d%Y")

data.frame(d_raw, d_new, d_try, bad, d_try2, d_YAY)
#        d_raw    d_new      d_try   bad   d_try2      d_YAY
# 1     112014 01012014 2014-01-01 FALSE 01012014 2014-01-01
# 2     122014 01022014 2014-01-02 FALSE 01022014 2014-01-02
# 3     132014 01032014 2014-01-03 FALSE 01032014 2014-01-03
# 4     142014 01042014 2014-01-04 FALSE 01042014 2014-01-04
# 5     152014 01052014 2014-01-05 FALSE 01052014 2014-01-05
# 6     162014 01062014 2014-01-06 FALSE 01062014 2014-01-06
```

I only did this with `Date`s in order to keep the example data set small. Doing this for `POSIXlt` would be very similar, except you would need to change the `as.Date` calls to `as.POSIxlt` and adjust the format accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

How about this (using regular expressions)

```
d_raw <- c("192001 16:00", "1102001 23:00", "1112001 0:00")

re <- "^(.+?)([1-9]|[1-3][0-9])(\\d{4}) (\\d{1,2}):(\\d{2})$"
m <- regexec(re, d_raw)
parts <- regmatches(d_raw, m)
lapply(parts, function(x) {
    x<-as.numeric(x[-1])
    ISOdate(x[3], x[1], x[2], x[4], x[5])
})

# [[1]]
# [1] "2001-01-09 16:00:00 GMT"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2001-01-10 23:00:00 GMT"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "2001-01-11 GMT"
```

If you had more test cases that would be helpful just to make sure the regular expression correctly works.

Comment: +1 I actually considered using regular expression too, but figured they would be relatively over-complicated for the average user.

Comment: +1 It's nice to have more than one approach to use here.  Thanks.