# R parse timestamp of form %m%d%Y with no leading zeroes

Tags: r, date

I have data with a timestamp of the form %m%d%Y with no leading zeroes.

Timestamp sample:

```
112001
1112001
```

Desired parsing

```
January 1 2001
January 11 2001 or November 1 2001 based on context
```

The timestamps are in sequential order. Is it possible to parse this data?

Comment: You'd probably need to paste a zero onto the front to get January.

Comment: I don't have leading zeros in this data set

Comment: No, I know, but the date-time parser needs 01 to recognize January.  When I do it I get November.

Comment: Are you opposed to pasting a zero onto the front?

Comment: Yes because there are several thousand data points

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25386730/271616) is very similar.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but I think there needs to be some prior work.  This follows the same premise as @hrbrmstr, which is I think is what needs to be done to be able to parse these dates.

```
> x <- c("112001", "1112001")
> x1 <- ifelse(substring(x, 1, 1) != 0, paste0(0, x), x)
> x2 <- ifelse(nchar(x1) == 7 & substring(x1, 3, 3) != 0, 
               paste0(substring(x1, 1, 2), 0, substring(x1, 3)), x1)
> library(lubridate)
> parse_date_time(x2, "mdy")
[1] "2001-01-01 UTC" "2001-01-11 UTC"
```

Comment: Haha,  almost.  But I get the year 2012 for the first element where they should both be 2001.  But I can tell you're about to blow my mind.

Comment: Ok Ok, the engine won't let me insert at multiple zero-width positions. `parse_date_time(gsub('^(?=.{6,7}$)', '0', perl=T, gsub('^\\d\\K(?!\\d{6})', '0', x, perl=T)), 'mdy')`

Comment: Mind officially blown.  You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Just for fun, of course your answer is more concise for this (+1). By the way thanks for the feedback on my question I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800042/overlapping-matches-in-r, you could post that as an answer and Ill upvote it.

Comment: @hwnd, thanks.  BTW, your regex skills are top notch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61154/discussion-between-hwnd-and-richard-scriven).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in all cases (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25391340/271616)).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - I saw that answer. Not really sure what to do, as if I change it the answer will be just like yours and I don't want to take your work.

Comment: Yeah, I think this question is a duplicate, but I don't want to vote as such, since my reputation level will automatically close it. I was hoping for some feedback on my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the basic logic handling for those date strings by length. You'll need to add logic for the "context", given that we have no idea how these are structured. I'm putting them in a vector for example:

```
dates <- c(112001, 1112001)

lapply(dates, function(x) {

  x <- as.character(x) 

  if (nchar(x) == 6) {
    as.Date(sprintf("0%s0%s%s", substr(x,1,1), substr(x,2,2), substr(x,3,6)), format="%m%d%Y")
  } else if (nchar(x) == 7) {
    as.Date(sprintf("0%s%s%s", substr(x,1,1), substr(x,2,3), substr(x,4,7)), format="%m%d%Y")    
  } else {
    as.Date(x, format="%m%d%Y")    
  }

})

## [[1]]
## [1] "2001-01-01"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "2001-01-11"
```

Comment: I used `lapply` so you'd see they are actual "date" objects. I'd (personally) probably use `sapply` but the output would have looked numeric and I didn't want to confuse matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can [parse a date](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strptime.html) from a string representation in a fixed format using `strptime`. You can then convert the result to a different representation using `strftime`.

Your desire to support non-uniquely parseable formats and decide "based on a context" is not as simple to implement and you probably want to avoid going down this way.

Comment: I must parse this data. strptime isn't parsing the data correctly because of the timestamp format.

Comment: Well, then prepare for some annoying coding. If a dirty hack will do for you, then I'd go for something explicit like "if (length(data) == 6) {handle 1-1-4 split} else if (length(data) == 7) {handle 1-2-4/2-1-4 and "decide based on the context"} else {handle 2-2-4 split}.

Comment: Even the very flexible `parse_date_time` or `parse_date_time2` from `lubridate` (with learning) would have a hard time with this format/requirements.